# How to go iphone settings bundle from my app with alerview button click?

Tags: ios, ios7

In my application first open alertview with button. if user click alertView button then i need to launch setting bundle in my device.

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs://"]];`

This is not working in IOS 7. Any having idea?

Comment: from iOS 6, you can't lauch settings bundle from your app

Comment: In BBC New app if user click share new and select Facebook then its going to Facebook setting bundle. Same as like i need to go my app setting bundle..

Comment: i think it was develop in iOS 5 so it can redirect to setting app.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this.

Because till now **(11th Jan 2013)** there is no url scheme available for settings app.

Apple provides built-in support for the **http, mailto, tel**, and **sms** URL schemes.